# Laravel - dynamic Eloquent Model depending on column value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my database I have a table `form_fields` with such structure:

```
id  | form_id | title   | type
1   | 1       | Subject | text
2   | 1       | Enquiry | textarea
3   | 1       | Logo    | file
```

And I have `Form` and `FormField` models, with such a relationship from `Form`:

```
public function fields()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Modules\Forms\Models\FormField', 'form_id', 'id');
}
```

Now is it possible to change which class is used based on the `type` field? So if I had `TextFormField`, `TextareaFormField` and `FileFormField`, all extending the base `FormField` Model, is it possible to get `Laravel` to use those? Or do I have to do it manually, so get the fields, iterate through them, and create new instances based on the type? Which doesn't seem hard, but it seems like a waste of resources, as if I have 20 fields, 20 `FormField` instances will be created, and then I will manually create 20 more?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a relation, you cannot, because when you access your fields

```
foreach($form->fields as $field) { ... }
```

You have already passed `$this->hasMany(...)`, it's gone and you could not provide a different class for every field.

What you can do is to recast your object to the proper class after you get it, doing something like:

**THIS IS A WORKING EXAMPLE**

```
Route::get('debug/cast', function () {
    $form = collect([['type' => 'text', 'name' => 'address'], ['type' => 'date', 'name' => 'birthdate']]);

    $fields = FieldTypeCollection::make($form->toArray());

    dd($fields);
});

class FieldTypeCollection extends Collection
{
    public function __construct($items)
    {
        parent::__construct($items);

        if (is_array($items)) {
            $this->recastAll();
        }
    }

    private function recastAll()
    {
        $items = [];

        foreach ($this->items as $key => $item) {
            $items[] = (new FieldFactory())->make($item);
        };

        $this->items = $items;
    }
}

class FieldFactory
{
    public function make($field)
    {
        if ($field['type'] == 'date') {
            $new = new DateInputFieldType();
        } else {
            $new = new TextInputFieldType();
        }

        return $this->importData($field, $new);
    }

    private function importData($old, $new)
    {
        $new->type = $old['type'];

        $new->name = $old['name'];

        return $new;
    }
}

class TextInputFieldType
{
    public $type;

    public $name;
}

class DateInputFieldType
{
    public $type;

    public $name;
}
```

You'll get this result:

[image]

Comment: wouldn't it be easyer to override the get method for the models something like (psuedocode) function get(){return SomeClassname::where(type, classId)}->get();

Answer (score 0):

If someone need help with a similar case... I guess you can use Polymorphic Relationships in this case!

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships